# Android device (except galaxy note 2) not able to get UDP packets

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am working on a client Server application in which the server (Desktop program written in Java) sends screen shots over UDP to my android device in same wireless network. Ofcourse since the datagram size is larger than udp standard size (65 K) I am creating slices of them and sending in a loop to my android device using UDP.

My problem is that it works perfectly on Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (android 4.2.2) but does not work in other android devices (even devices running same android version For ex galaxy tab 3, galaxy Note 1). The code gets stuck on socket.receive(datagram) and does not even receive single packet.

can some one please help me on this ???

```
public ClientListener(int port, int fps, AppDelegate del){
        delegate = del;
        framesPerSecond = fps;

        try{

            serverAddr = getLocalIpAddress();
            dgp = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
        }
        serverPort = port;
    }



    public void run() {
           try {
               socket = new DatagramSocket(serverPort, serverAddr);
               connected = true;

               Timer timer = new Timer();
               int frames = 1000/framesPerSecond;

               Log.e("FRAMES", ""+frames);
               timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(getImageTask, 0, frames);

               listen();               
           }
           catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e("ClientActivity", "Client Connection Error", e);
           }
     }



private void listen()
    {

        while(connected){

            try{

                socket.receive(dgp); //gets stuck here on devices other than note 2




                byte[] data = dgp.getData();
                System.out.println("data received in datagram clientListener====="+data);
            /* Read header infomation */
            short session = (short) (data[1] & 0xff);
            short slices = (short) (data[2] & 0xff);
            int maxPacketSize = (int) ((data[3] & 0xff) << 8 | (data[4] & 0xff)); // mask

            short slice = (short) (data[5] & 0xff);
            int size = (int) ((data[6] & 0xff) << 8 | (data[7] & 0xff)); // mask



                System.out.println("------------- PACKET -------------");
                System.out.println("SESSION_START = "
                        + ((data[0] & SESSION_START) == SESSION_START));
                System.out.println("SSESSION_END = "
                        + ((data[0] & SESSION_END) == SESSION_END));
                System.out.println("SESSION NR = " + session);
                System.out.println("SLICES = " + slices);
                System.out.println("MAX PACKET SIZE = " + maxPacketSize);
                System.out.println("SLICE NR = " + slice);
                System.out.println("SIZE = " + size);
                System.out.println("------------- PACKET -------------\n");


            /* If SESSION_START falg is set, setup start values */
            if ((data[0] & SESSION_START) == SESSION_START) {
                if (session != currentSession) {
                    currentSession = session;
                    slicesStored = 0;
                    /* Consturct a appropreately sized byte array */
                    imageData = new byte[slices * maxPacketSize];
                    slicesCol = new int[slices];
                    sessionAvailable = true;
                }
            }

            /* If package belogs to current session */
            if (sessionAvailable && session == currentSession) {
                if (slicesCol != null && slicesCol[slice] == 0) {
                    slicesCol[slice] = 1;
                    System.arraycopy(data, HEADER_SIZE, imageData, slice
                            * maxPacketSize, size);
                    slicesStored++;
                }
            }

            /* If image is complete dispay it */
            if (slicesStored == slices) {
                ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                        imageData);
                 Bitmap bp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                         delegate.getController().setImage(bp);




                         Log.e("Testing", "Received image");






            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys for my stupidity. Actually for some strange reason, the server could not cater to multiple connections from multiple android devices in the same time. Only one device should be connected to the server or request for connection. In my case I was already logged in though my note 2 and was at the same time trying with another device. So my other device was not able to receive packets.